# Can I make bash stop parsing and validating a certain alias?

Tags: bash, bashrc, bash-alias

I'm using Fedora 25, and have added the following alias to my bash profile:

```
alias releasenotes="dnf updateinfo --refresh info `dnf check-update | cut -d '.' -f 1 | xargs` | less"
```

(I can't use straight-up `dnf updateinfo info` because of https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1405191)

My alias works, but the command takes about 10 seconds to run, and since bash parses and validates all aliases when the profile is sourced, creating a new shell results in a 10-second hang. This is annoying.

Is there any way to make bash not try to parse and validate aliases--or just that one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My best guess is you should probably use *single quotes* around the alias definition.

I know that when using double quotes, shell variables are replaced with their content at the alias definition stage (like you said parsing and validating) and backticks or shell substitution like $(command).

A better explanation is in this [Unix SE question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/319655/command-substitution-within-single-quotes-for-alias#319661)!

If that doesn't help making the prompt load faster again, define a shell function instead of an alias.

edit: Don't forget to swap the cut argument to double-quotes like quixotic mentioned.

Comment: That did it! You answered first, so you get the credit.

Answer (score 9):

`bash` is interpreting your quoted string, and that interpretation executes the embedded `dnf check-update` command.  This execution is what takes up the time during the alias definition, not the main `dnf updateinfo` command you're aliasing.  Try a contrived example based on `sleep` and note how the `alias` itself takes 5 seconds:

```
alias sleep5="echo 'wake' ; `sleep 5` ; echo 'done'"
```

Use single-quotes to avoid the interpretation:

```
alias releasenotes='dnf updateinfo --refresh info `dnf check-update | cut -d "." -f 1 | xargs` | less'
```

Don't forget to swap the `cut` argument to double-quotes.